# why i m not receiving message with my twilio number which i bought?

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-api

When receive message from my twilio account.
i got message with different number like 400012 or 641011 like this
but not my twilio number which i use to send message is not display in my inbox when i receive message

can i do something so that whenever someone receive message from my twilio number the number in inbox showing is also twilio number?

```
 var client = new twilio.RestClient(twilio_account_sid, twilio_auth_token);

            client.messages.create({
                body: msg,
                to: to,  // Text this number
                from: twilio_number // From a valid Twilio number
            }, function(err, message) {
                if(err) {
                    console.error(err.message);
                }else{
                    console.log("here send sms ... ... ...");
                }
            });
```

my code is simple like above

Comment: Which country are you sending your messages to?

Comment: right now  i am sending in india but i have to send in malasia, Brunei Darussalam, Indonesia, Thailand, Philippines, Singapore, Viet Nam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There are some limitations when sending messages to certain countries from a Twilio number. India is particularly restrictive and will not let you retain your original number. Users can still send messages to your Twilio number, they will just receive them from a shortened number like the ones you shared.

You can read up on the restrictions for sending messages to India in [this support article](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223134167-Limitations-sending-SMS-messages-to-Indian-mobile-devices) and by checking out the [SMS guidelines for India](https://www.twilio.com/sms/guidelines/in).

The restrictions for the other countries you need to send to will be different. For example, [in Malaysia your long code phone number is preserved](https://www.twilio.com/sms/guidelines/my). Check out the restrictions for your countries here: https://www.twilio.com/sms/guidelines

Let me know if that helps at all.